# A site is available but it always responses "Internal Server Error"

Tags: python

The code looks like:

```
url ="http://www.example.com" 
for a in range(0,10):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    postdata ="info=123456"+str(a)
    urllib2.urlopen(url, postdata)
```

which just post some data to a specific URL(e.g. http://www.example.com), however, I always get the error message,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    urllib2.urlopen(url, postdata)
  File "c:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "c:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "c:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "c:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

I am sure the site is working, so how can I fix the problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try POST'ing the same data to the same URL with `curl` or a similar tool. The site must have responded with the 500, it's either not working as you expect or found out that a script is being used to access it (impolite, but some sites do that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you're sure the site is working, yet it returns an error.  Why don't you try doing whatever you did to determine that the site is working, while running a network logger like wireshark, and then run your test program to see if the two are really issuing the same queries.  If not, you've found the problem.

Otherwise, take a look at the server's logs.  A much more descriptive error message should be found there.  If it's not your server, consider asking whoever does own it.

Answer (score 1):

Some websites don't accept requests from urllib. Try to change the User-Agent.